# The auto login configuration can't pass the first appeared screen after reboot/shutdown

Tags: authentication

I am a Linux beginner user.

Because the device is a tablet, I would like to can use it "take away" also without the attached wireless keyboard, that's why, I intend to use the auto login.

I would like to resolve if it is posssible the next issues, without to install a login manager.

It seams that the auto login could not pass the first screen appeared after reboot, or after shutdown.

My auto login configuration

```
    sudo apt-get install mingetty


sudo su
exec /bin/login -f xdpsx < /dev/tty1 > /dev/tty1 2>&1
__________________
sudo mkdir -pv /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/
_____________
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin username --noclear %I 38400 linux
_____________
systemctl enable getty@tty1.service
__________________
File: /home/xdpsx/.bash_profile                   


if [[ -z $DISPLAY ]] && [[ $(tty) = /dev/tty1 ]]; then
 exec startx
fi
_______________________________________
/home/xdpsx/.xinitrc


if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ] ; then
 for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?*.sh ; do
    [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
 done
 unset f
fi


sleep 5 && /usr/bin/onboard &
exec jwm


    ~/.xsession-errors
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Thu Oct 27 09:55:40 CEST 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 4382 requests (2277 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Thu Oct 27 09:58:29 CEST 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list
xterm: fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) or KillClient on X server ":0"
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Thu Oct 27 10:06:06 CEST 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list

(hexchat:7006): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 8441 was not found when attempting to remove it

** (pale moon:7026): WARNING **: Cannot launch default application: No application is registered as handling this file

** (pale moon:7026): WARNING **: Cannot launch default application: No application is registered as handling this file
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Thu Oct 27 22:05:43 CEST 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list

** (pale moon:1172): WARNING **: Cannot launch default application: No application is registered as handling this file

** (pale moon:1172): WARNING **: Cannot launch default application: No application is registered as handling this file

** (pale moon:1172): WARNING **: Cannot launch default application: No application is registered as handling this file

** (pale moon:1172): WARNING **: Cannot launch default application: No application is registered as handling this file

(pale moon:1172): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_clipboard_get_for_display: assertion '!display->closed' failed

(pale moon:1172): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_clipboard_get_for_display: assertion '!display->closed' failed
XIO:  fatal IO error 4 (Interrupted system call) on X server ":0"
      after 71573 requests (71573 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Fri Oct 28 05:42:22 CEST 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list

** (pale moon:2243): WARNING **: Cannot launch default application: No application is registered as handling this file

** (pale moon:2243): WARNING **: Cannot launch default application: No application is registered as handling this file

** (pale moon:2243): WARNING **: Cannot launch default application: No application is registered as handling this file

** (pale moon:2243): WARNING **: Cannot launch default application: No application is registered as handling this file
lxterminal: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 241406 requests (241406 known processed) with 1 events remaining.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Fri Oct 28 07:14:33 CEST 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Fri Oct 28 07:24:14 CEST 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 36042 requests (36042 known processed) with 1 events remaining.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Fri Oct 28 07:34:28 CEST 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list
XIO:  fatal IO error 4 (Interrupted system call) on X server ":0"
      after 23261 requests (23261 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Fri Oct 28 07:40:57 CEST 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 15658 requests (15658 known processed) with 1 events remaining.
Terminated
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Fri Oct 28 07:45:18 CEST 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 17789 requests (17649 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Fri Oct 28 07:50:50 CEST 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list

(hexchat:1901): libnotify-WARNING **: Failed to connect to proxy
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 715680 requests (715680 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Terminated
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Fri Oct 28 16:02:06 CEST 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list

(hexchat:1252): libnotify-WARNING **: Failed to connect to proxy
ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4771:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Fri Oct 28 17:02:33 CEST 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 765817 requests (765817 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":1"
      after 296472 requests (296445 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Sat Oct 29 08:47:21 CEST 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 878 requests (878 known processed) with 1 events remaining.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Sat Oct 29 08:49:26 CEST 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 2144 requests (2144 known processed) with 1 events remaining.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Sat Oct 29 08:51:52 CEST 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 2002 requests (2002 known processed) with 1 events remaining.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Sat Oct 29 08:53:14 CEST 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 75802 requests (75802 known processed) with 1 events remaining.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Sat Oct 29 10:57:37 CEST 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list
SSL_read/read: No route to host
XIO:  fatal IO error 4 (Interrupted system call) on X server ":0"
      after 451418 requests (451418 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Sat Oct 29 14:18:12 CEST 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list
Vector smash protection is enabled.
NOTE: child process received `Goodbye', closing down
Vector smash protection is enabled.
NOTE: child process received `Goodbye', closing down

(hexchat:4368): libnotify-WARNING **: Failed to connect to proxy
Vector smash protection is enabled.
SSL_read/read: No route to host

(hexchat:4368): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 69936 was not found when attempting to remove it

(hexchat:4368): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 69936 was not found when attempting to remove it

(hexchat:4368): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 69936 was not found when attempting to remove it

(hexchat:4368): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 69936 was not found when attempting to remove it

(hexchat:4368): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 69936 was not found when attempting to remove it
NOTE: child process received `Goodbye', closing down
Vector smash protection is enabled.
NOTE: child process received `Goodbye', closing down
Vector smash protection is enabled.

(plugin-container:11290): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 497285 was not found when attempting to remove it

(plugin-container:11290): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 497301 was not found when attempting to remove it

(plugin-container:11290): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 497700 was not found when attempting to remove it

(plugin-container:11290): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 497716 was not found when attempting to remove it

(plugin-container:11290): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 497729 was not found when attempting to remove it

(plugin-container:11290): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 497749 was not found when attempting to remove it

(plugin-container:11290): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 497760 was not found when attempting to remove it

(plugin-container:11290): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 497771 was not found when attempting to remove it

(plugin-container:11290): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 497772 was not found when attempting to remove it

(plugin-container:11290): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 497781 was not found when attempting to remove it
Vector smash protection is enabled.
NOTE: child process received `Goodbye', closing down

(hexchat:16218): libnotify-WARNING **: Failed to connect to proxy
Vector smash protection is enabled.
NOTE: child process received `Goodbye', closing down
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 5006525 requests (5006525 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Terminated
Terminated
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Mon Oct 31 06:28:18 CET 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":1"
      after 1470 requests (1470 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Mon Oct 31 06:29:54 CET 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list

(hexchat:1364): libnotify-WARNING **: Failed to connect to proxy
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 174922 requests (174464 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Mon Oct 31 07:33:50 CET 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list

(hexchat:1230): libnotify-WARNING **: Failed to connect to proxy
Vector smash protection is enabled.
NOTE: child process received `Goodbye', closing down
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 118231 requests (118231 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Mon Oct 31 08:08:00 CET 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list

(hexchat:1204): libnotify-WARNING **: Failed to connect to proxy
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 15620 requests (15620 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Mon Oct 31 08:14:17 CET 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list

(hexchat:1210): libnotify-WARNING **: Failed to connect to proxy
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 68225 requests (68225 known processed) with 1 events remaining.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Mon Oct 31 08:42:30 CET 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list

(hexchat:1231): libnotify-WARNING **: Failed to connect to proxy
XIO:  fatal IO error 4 (Interrupted system call) on X server ":0"
      after 79561 requests (79561 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Mon Oct 31 09:08:52 CET 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list

(hexchat:1284): libnotify-WARNING **: Failed to connect to proxy
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 18835 requests (18721 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Mon Oct 31 09:15:20 CET 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list

(hexchat:1210): libnotify-WARNING **: Failed to connect to proxy
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 92706 requests (92706 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
lxterminal: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Mon Oct 31 09:39:29 CET 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 3381 requests (3381 known processed) with 1 events remaining.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Mon Oct 31 09:40:55 CET 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list
lxterminal: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 24140 requests (24140 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Mon Oct 31 09:47:26 CET 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list

(hexchat:1284): libnotify-WARNING **: Failed to connect to proxy
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
Can't find symbol 'glXCreateContextAttribsARB'.
Vector smash protection is enabled.
NOTE: child process received `Goodbye', closing down
Vector smash protection is enabled.
SSL_read/read: Network is unreachable
XIO:  fatal IO error 4 (Interrupted system call) on X server ":0"
      after 1072184 requests (1072184 known processed) with 1 events remaining.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Tue Nov  1 06:49:20 CET 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list

(pale moon:1476): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_clipboard_set_with_data: assertion 'targets != NULL' failed

(pale moon:1476): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_clipboard_set_with_data: assertion 'targets != NULL' failed
XIO:  fatal IO error 4 (Interrupted system call) on X server ":0"
      after 151734 requests (151734 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Tue Nov  1 07:58:47 CET 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 97302 requests (97302 known processed) with 1 events remaining.
Terminated
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Tue Nov  1 08:38:59 CET 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list
Vector smash protection is enabled.
NOTE: child process received `Goodbye', closing down
Vector smash protection is enabled.
NOTE: child process received `Goodbye', closing down
Vector smash protection is enabled.
NOTE: child process received `Goodbye', closing down
Vector smash protection is enabled.
NOTE: child process received `Goodbye', closing down
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 658028 requests (658028 known processed) with 1 events remaining.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Tue Nov  1 14:53:12 CET 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list
Vector smash protection is enabled.
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 37136 requests (37136 known processed) with 1 events remaining.
lxterminal: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
plugin-container: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Xsession: X session started for xdpsx at Tue Nov  1 15:08:07 CET 2016
localuser:xdpsx being added to access control list
Vector smash protection is enabled.
NOTE: child process received `Goodbye', closing down
X connection to :0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown
```

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log` https://paste.ubuntu.com/23414804/

`journalctl -b`  http://paste.ubuntu.com/23412613/

```
systemctl status getty@tty1
● getty@tty1.service - Getty on tty1
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service; enabled; ven
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d
           └─autologin.conf, override.conf
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2016-11-01 19:23:44 CET; 41mi
     Docs: man:agetty(8)
           man:systemd-getty-generator(8)
           http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html
 Main PID: 1563 (login)
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-getty.slice/getty@tty1.service
           ‣ 1563 /bin/login -f      

Nov 01 19:23:44 1o2n3b4t5y6u systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty1.
Nov 01 19:23:44 1o2n3b4t5y6u login[1563]: pam_unix(login:session): 
lines 1-14/14 (END)
```

After reboot it is stuck on the first appeared screen which it seams that is the systemd screen `/dev/sda1: clean 1123123/1231312 files 12312312/13212312 blocks.`

The only way to pass this screen is to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> and after that the autologin to x works automatically.

I don't use any login manager, or any desktop environment, only jwm.

I am 99% percent sure that the same config passed also the above systemd first screen On Ubuntu 16.10, but it seams that on Ubuntu 16.04 it can't.

While the above screen is standing by the login manager which will appear after <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> is appearing "like a ghost" for a few "mili seconds" like it would trying to start in the background of the first screen `/dev/sda1: clean 1123123/1231312 files 12312312/13212312 blocks.` but it can't until I don't <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>.

Comment: I think this question fits better @ [unix.stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Agreed. I tried to flag it for migration, but I couldn't put in that option. Hopefully the mods will notice these comments.